# BizTalk 2013 Save a copy of received EDI file

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2013

I am trying to save copies of the EDI files I am receiving from an ftp server. I have tried using a send port to a file, but the parties will not resolve and it is using Fallback settings so I cannot set up proper validation, specifically allow leading and trailing zeros. Is there a better way to save a copy of the received EDI file.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a Archiving [Custom Pipeline component](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11679.biztalk-list-of-custom-pipeline-components.aspx) to the Receive Pipeline works for most scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

The solution of Dijkgraaf (archiving pipeline component) makes a lot of sense, but just to provide you with other options:

The EDI files come in from somewhere. If this is a FILE or an FTP server for example, you could consider to script the archival of the file, by scripting the file move from the incoming folder to a folder where BizTalk is listening to. At that point it is very easy to make an extra copy of the original file before BizTalk is actually even seeing this. This can be done by a Scheduled Task or by BizTalk itself (PassThru pipelines).

Typically, it's not a bad design to separate your incoming folder from the folder where BizTalk will pick it up. This mostly depends on your own preferences. Do consider however that your BizTalk Server is often monitored and logged and your external scripts/scheduled tasks are not. 

In that case I always tend to choose for the BizTalk 'PassThru' solution, since if this fails, you will be notified via the event log.

Answer (score 2):

Before doing any custom work, take some to see if any of the built it BizTalk features can satisfy your requirement.  There are two features specifically that address your situation:

EDI and AS2 Status Reporting - Stores incoming and outgoing EDI transactions and interchanges with their delivery status (997).  The UI is built into BizTalk Administrator.  Details here: [EDI and AS2 Status Reporting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226463.aspx)

BizTalk Tracking:  Can store any incoming or outgoing message.  The search and retrieve UI is also part of BizTalk Administrator.  Sample of how to use Tracking to archive messages: [BizTalk Archiving, The BizTalk Way](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32616.biztalk-archiving-the-biztalk-way.aspx)

Finally, you can consider a fully out-of-band solution by saving copies of the files before they even get to your BizTalk app.

Comment: Great suggestions, I'd just add that if they're dealing with very large interchanges the custom archiving route is likely the way to go.